# Log file where see executed scripts/apps in Linux/Unix

Tags: logging, sh, ksh

According to a workmate question i would want to know if there is a log file, or something equivalent, to see where a script (sh or ksh file) was executed. The problem is when a script doesn't left execution info in a log file and was executed by other user or scheduled in crontab or control-M.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a MTA like postfix or simply SSMTP, you can put an email in your crontab like this :

```
MAILTO=you@domain.tld
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
DISPLAY=:0

* * * * * command
```

When command will run, if it's well designed and print errors on STDERR, crontab will send you an email

Answer (score 0):

you may using #!/bin/bash -x, and all debug info send to mail.